# With multiple select dropdown lists, get the selected value from the one I clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I've got multiple < select > dropdown lists. Every dropdown list has its own id and is assigned like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<12; $i++) {
    echo '<select class="selectpicker" id="select$i">
              <option value="x">text</option>
          </select>';
}
```

In jQuery, how do i get the selected option of the select dropdown list i have clicked? So far I've got the following code:

```
<script>
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    $("#select" + i + "").change(function () {
        alert("Im inside a select box!");

        var selectValue = document.getElementById('select' + i + '').value;
        var selectOption = $("#select" + i + " option[value=" + selectValue + "]").text(); 

        alert(selectOption);      
    });
}
</script>
```

It does alert "Im inside a select box!" whichever select box i click. But it doesn't alert the selected option though. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

to start off in your php you have `"for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {"` and in your js you have `"for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {"`, shouldn't the `"i < 12"` be `"i < 10"` in your js? it may mismatch the select id

Comment: I just checked, i have < 12 at both the php and js. I changed it in my post.

Comment: OK, so when i alerted the variable 'i' it alerted 12 everytime. I should be able to figure this out now I know this :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it. I just check on any select dropdown list with $("select") and from there on I was able to get the selected option.

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var selectValue = $(this).attr("id");
    var selectOption = $("#" + selectValue + " option:selected").text();
});
```